# compare between SQL Date and C# Datetime.now.date

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012-express

How can I compare between SQL server (`Date`) and C# (`DateTime.Now.Date`), 
I want to give me message box about this compare.

```
public Form1()
{
    DateTime dat1 = new DateTime();
    dat1 = DateTime.Now.Date;

    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dateTimePicker1.ToString == DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("date equla datetime.now.date", "etention", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

}

private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // selected this date in SQLserver
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that has anything to do with SQL here. You've got a DateTimePicker presumably, and you want to compare *that* with `DateTime.Now.Date` (which is more easily written as `DateTime.Today` btw) but we don't know how that relates to SQL or even what type of app this is (web, WinForms, WPF, something else)?

Comment: I'm not sure, are you asking for assistance on creating the SQL-Query or is it about data-types in general?

Comment: If you're wanting to compare dates, the *worst* step you can take is converting them to strings (as you're currently attempting in `Form1_Load`). So long as they're in *appropriately* types variables (e.g. `DateTime`) comparisons, etc, should just work. As soon as you convert to strings, you suddenly have to consider what *format* the dates are going to be in.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both to same format.
In your case `dateTimepicker`is string and SQL date is not retrieved any where.
Select SQL date use `getdate()` then convert both to same format and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition as this in the Form_Load event:

```
    if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("date equla datetime.now.date", "etention", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Comment: If I put this code in Timer, Do you think program will  give me answer Automatic